# Facebook Graph API access token is different from what I am getting via Oauth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I made a facebook app.

The app is to get all the pictures my page is tagged in.

When I use the graph api explorer with graph api explorer as the application to get the access token, This access token returns me all the data required(In this case photos my page was tagged in using (me/accounts) then get the access token of my page and then me/photos/tagged)

But the same process when I repeat with selecting my application in the graph api explorer. It does not give all the data

Both have same permissions.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: My gut tells me it's something about permission of your app. Can you supply the saved sessions of both situations?

Answer (score 0):

I think is a little bug fix of API graph:

```
FB.api(
      '/id_cta',
      'POST',
      {**"access_token":access_token**,"web_url":url},
      function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
);
```

**Important**: ask for scope **manage_pages** and **pages_manage_cta**.